# Join tuples in list based on length of next tuple

Tags: python, tuples

For example I have a list with a lot of tuples of different lengths e.g.

```
list_with_length_of_tuples = [2000, 2000, 1700, 300, 299, 1699, 2000, 2000, 300, 200, 1499]
```

So I want to get a list that will join tuples with length shorter than 2000 together. To get an idea we have to get the following:

```
list_with_length_of_tuples_1= [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 1998, 2000, 2000, 1999]
```

It looks weird and it is not a trivial task, but the idea is that I have a list of tuples of different length but all of them should be equal to about 2000 (it can be in range approx from 1995 to 2005), but some of the tuples are broken into several parts and they need to be joined together to get the desired length of about 2000. The difficulty is than some of the tuples broken into several parts and the next tuple is broken in several parts too. Is there a way to solve this problem? My explanation sounds vague but if you have an additional clarifying questions please ask.

Comment: Well, calling it not trivial is a bit of an understatement. It's basically an instance of the [**Knapsack problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)! :)

Comment: So basically the problem is: If you have a list like `[1998, 5, 1980, 10]` whether to add the `5` to the first or second tuple, so all tuples are within 1995-2005, right? I guess you could use a backtracking algorithm. In theory, the complexity of that could be really bad, but in practice you'd only have to branch if both adding and not adding the element to the current tuple would be valid, which should not be the case too often.

Comment: Should order be preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if computational time is not a problem, convert everything to a list then use a simple foor loop.

```
#T=[some tuples with the above length]
tmp=[]
for t in T:
    if not tmp or len(tmp[-1])+len(t)>2000:
        tmp.append(list(t))
    else:
        tmp[-1]+=t
result=[tuple(t) for t in tmp]
```

More efficiently, deal with the lengths first:

```
list_with_length_of_tuples = [2000, 2000, 1700, 300, 299, 1699, 2000, 2000, 300, 200, 1499]
#T=[some tuples with the above length]
tmp=[]
for i,v in enumerate(list_with_length_of_tuples):
    if not tmp or tmp[-1][1]+v>2000:
        tmp.append([[i],v])
    else:
        tmp[-1]=tmp[-1][0]+[i],tmp[-1][1]+v
result=[]
for ndxx, _ in tmp:
    result.append[(z for n in ndxx for z in T[n])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# O(nc) time complexity where n is length of list and c is the max length of chunks
def form_correct_tuples(ls):
    correct_length = []
    number_of_parts = 0
    
    for idx, val in enumerate(ls):
        if number_of_parts > 1:
            number_of_parts -= 1
            if val != 2000:
                continue
        
        if 1995 <= val <= 2005:
            correct_length.append(val)
        else:
            sum_ = 0
            while sum_ < 1995 or sum_ > 2005:
                sum_ += ls[idx]
                idx += 1
                number_of_parts += 1

            correct_length.append(sum_)

    return correct_length
```

This code first checks whether current number is in between 1995 and 2005 or not. If yes, add it to new list, otherwise create temporary `sum_` variable and add each part to it while `sum_` reaches in between 1995 and 2005. Finally, in each iteration you check if there were any parts in list to not go through them again using `number_of_parts` variable. Testing it with your current input:

```
result = form_correct_tuples(list_with_length_of_tuples)
# -> [2000, 2000, 2000, 1998, 2000, 2000, 1999]
```